# sed/awk replacing cannot work fine in Makefile on Windows

Tags: windows, awk, sed, makefile

`sed/awk` is not working as expected in my Windows Makefile.

I have a text file with \', I want to replace it with ''

```bash
cat << EOF > a.txt
\'
\'
''
""
EOF
```

I can use `sed/awk` to replace it, this works fine on Windows Git Bash:

```bash
sed -i "s/\\\'/''/g" a.txt && cat a.txt

awk '{gsub(/'"\\\'"'/,"\047\047"); print}' a.txt > b.txt && cat b.txt
```

but with this statement in a Makefile, it will not work:

```bash
cat Makefile
replace:
    @sed -i "s/\\\'/''/g" a.txt

re:
    @awk '{gsub(/'"\\\'"'/,"\047\047"); print}' a.txt > b.txt


# run make command, it did nothing but appending '' to each line
make replace && cat a.txt
# or
make re && cat b.txt

\'''
\'''
''''
""''
```

Comment: On Linux, your makefile works for me as you seem to intend.  I'm inclined to suspect, then, that your windows `make` is using a different shell than Bash to execute the recipe in your makefile.  You should be able to control that by [setting the `SHELL` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-environment_002c-SHELL-in) to a suitable shell.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I tried adding `SHELL = /bin/bash` or `SHELL = C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe` or `SHELL = C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` to the Makefile, but that didn't work. I also tried `awk` and it still didn't work.

Comment: What character encoding do the files have on windows? If it is UTF-16 (like windows notepad uses), none of the Linux utilities will work with it. Make sure all files have UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Yes, it's UTF-8. Running sed/awk replacements (as described above) directly in windows git bash is ok, but it's not okay when used in Makefile on Windows

Comment: Hiding the command with `@` is counterproductive as you can't see what's going on. Once you have resolved this, don't put it back; run with `make -s` if you don't want to see what `make` is doing.

Comment: How did you install Make?

Comment: Quoting is always a bit unhinged (mad) in Windows. Just for kicks, and to rule it out, maybe try putting your `awk` and `sed` scripts in separate files and run with `awk -f script.awk` and `sed  -f script.sed`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Using scoop.

Comment: So what's the output if you remove the `@`s and try again?

Comment: @tripleee The inverse is also an option, you can always `--trace` or `--debug=print` to see the commands.

Comment: *"Using scoop"* I know for sure that [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) has a sane Make. Maybe try that?

Comment: @tripleee No change, except for the running command.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Installed `msys2`, then `pacman -S make`. Using this make, it's `fine`. Nice :). But I still want to use make in Windows Git Bash, since other people mainly use git bash

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is actually with git bash, could be a weird version of Make in Scoop. Git Bash is based on a stripped-off version of MSYS2, so I'd just tell your users to use it directly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `make` installed by `scoop` is weird. I tried to use `scoop make` in `msys2`, which has the same issue, but using `make` installed by `pacman` is okay.